# How to solve generics error CS0311?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, csla

I have searched the web and stackoverflow and found many posts that deals with CS0311 error. None of the scenarios are close to mine. I have a generic class that inherits from a generic class.

Please note that `BusinessBase` is a class in the `CSLA` framework

What am I missing ?

```
public interface Itest
{
    int Digit();
}

class BB : Itest
{
    public int Digit()
    {
        return 20;
    }
}


class Test<T> : BusinessBase<T>, Itest where T : Test<T>, Itest
{
    public int Digit()
    {
        return 30;
    }
}

Test<Itest> test = new Test<Itest>(); //error CS0311
```

> Error CS0311  The type `'MyTestApp.Itest'` cannot be used as type parameter `'T'` in the generic type or method `'A<T>'`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `'MyTestApp.Itest'` to `'MyTestApp.A<MyTestApp.Itest>'`. MyTestApp

Comment: You don't need the `Test<T>` bit in the where clause, try `where T : Itest`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method - Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529746/type-cannot-be-used-as-type-parameter-t-in-the-generic-type-or-method-why)

Comment: every `Test<T>` is  `Itest` but every `Itest` is not `Test<T>` that's why it fails (just like `BB` you have there. `Itest` may be `BB`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go something like this:

```
interface Itest {}

class BusinessBase<T> {

}

class Test<T> : BusinessBase<T>, Itest where T : Test<T>, Itest {
    public int Digit() {
        return 30;
    }
}

class IT : Test<IT>, Itest {

}

class Program {
    public static int Main() {

        var t = new Test<IT>();
        t.Digit();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Which to me is a really awful use of generics, but that is how CSLA works....

Comment: Thank you. I would have given you a vote however I'm a new user and don't have sufficient privileges. Will do once I acquire it :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the compiler. `T` in your scenario is `Itest`. Your `where` condition demands that `T : Test<T>` (which immediately sounds suspect), which would require that `ITest : Test<ITest>` ... but `ITest` ***clearly doesn't*** (and can't) `: Test<ITest>`.

It is very very unclear what you intended to do, but I *suspect* you mean:

```
class Test<T> where T : Itest
```

and:

```
Test<BB> test = new Test<BB>();
```

Comment: I have edited my code. I'm inheriting from a CSLA object. If I don't  include Test<T> in the constraints I would get a class definition error.