# How to convert behavior to generic type in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Behavior which is responsible for coloring text if he is too short. I want to use behavior not only with Entry control but with a lot of others like Search Bar or Editor. How I can transform this Behavior to generic type? Is it possible? I hope you understand what I mean.

```
public class MinLengthValidatonBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MinLengthProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("MinLength", typeof(int), typeof(MinLengthValidatonBehavior), 0);

    public static readonly BindableProperty InvalidColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("InvalidColor", typeof(string), typeof(EmailValidatonBehavior), "e4375b");

    public int MinLength
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(MinLengthProperty);
        set => SetValue(MinLengthProperty, value);
    }

    public string InvalidColor
    {
        get => GetValue(InvalidColorProperty).ToString();
        set => SetValue(InvalidColorProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged += BindableTextChanged;
    }

    private void BindableTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Entry).TextColor =
            e.NewTextValue.Length < MinLength ? Color.FromHex(InvalidColor) : Color.Default;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged -= BindableTextChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MinLengthValidatonBehavior<T> : Behavior<T>` and specify type correctly too  `typeof(MinLengthValidatonBehavior<T>` be sure that properties that you bind are avaible in all T elements that you use.

You can learn more in official web page.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/behaviors/introduction/

Comment: Sorry I haven't written for so long. I tried this before but I have error: `The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Behavior<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject'.`

Comment: There is a similar post with you're problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529746/type-cannot-be-used-as-type-parameter-t-in-the-generic-type-or-method-why). Take a look and if it is not enough try giving more datail.