# Complex inheritance with generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Let's say I have a set of classes/interfaces:

```
class ObjectData { }
class UnitData : ObjectData { }
class Component1Data : UnitData { }
class Component2Data : UnitData { }

interface IObject { }
interface IUnit : IObject { }
interface IComponent1 : IUnit { }
interface IComponent2 : IUnit { }

abstract class Object<D, O, I>
    where D : ObjectData
    where O : Object<D, O, I>, I, new()
    where I : IObject
{ }
```

The point of primary interest here is an `Object` class which is a base generic class in some hierarchy. Type-param "O" is a way to specify type of an actual class which is derived from the `Object`. Thus, something like this can be declared and compiled w/o problems:

```
class Unit : Object<UnitData, Unit, IUnit>, IUnit { }
```

But what i want to do, is to define another generic "2nd-level" class derived from Object that should also behave as a base class for a couple of similar "3rd-level" entities. And it have to be non-abstract because it is also some sort of an entity. So i need to define something like this:

```
class Unit<D, I> : Object<D, Unit<D, I>, I>, IUnit
    where D : UnitData
    where I : IUnit
{ }

class Component1 : Unit<Component1Data, IComponent1>, IComponent1 { }
class Component2 : Unit<Component2Data, IComponent2>, IComponent2 { }
```

And it produces following compilation error:

```
error CS0311: The type 'Unit<D, I>' cannot be used as type parameter 'O' in the generic type or method 'Object<D, O, I>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Unit<D, I>' to 'I'.
```

The question is why? In my vision if `Unit<D, I>` is implementing `IUnit`, and param "I" is specified as `where I : IUnit`, then all should be fine. That's how i see it. What i don't see?

Comment: this has to be the most convoluted use of generics I've ever seen...

Comment: How `O` will be used inside of `Object<D, O, I>`? Post the sample code, please.

Comment: Like this for example:
 public static O Create(D data)
 {
  return data != null
   ? new O { Data = data }
   : null;
 }

 public D Data { get; private set; }

Comment: I'd like to quote Eric Lippert (an authority on C#, since I am not myself one): "More specifically, I would say that you are abusing generics. The fact that you've made type relationships that are too complicated for you to analyze yourself is evidence that you ought to simplify the whole thing; if you're not keeping all the type relationships straight and you wrote the thing then your users surely will not be able to keep it straight either." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434851/why-does-a-generic-type-constraint-result-in-a-no-implicit-reference-conversion

Comment: Maybe Eric is right, but does this answer my question?

Comment: Hence why that was a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: @drty: so, all this hell is just for having static factory method in base class? Are you kidding?

Comment: No, i'm not. There are actually much more uses of "O" in real implementation. It was just an example. "O" is needed. W/o it it's losing some flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the problem;

```
interface IObject { }
interface IUnit : IObject { }
interface IFoo : IUnit { }

abstract class Object<O, I>
    where O : Object<O, I>, I, new()
    where I : IObject
{}

class Unit : Object<Unit, IUnit>, IUnit
{
}
```

This is happy and compiles. I've replaced `I` here with `IUnit`. Now change to something more derived:

```
class Unit : Object<Unit, IFoo>, IUnit
```

and you get the error:

> The type 'Unit' cannot be used as type parameter 'O' in the generic
>   type or method 'Object'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'Unit' to 'IFoo'.

So... `Unit`, which derives from `IUnit` cannot be converted to `IFoo` even though both implement `IUnit`... because `Unit` doesn't derive from `IFoo`...  which is a condition on Object:

```
where O : Object<O, I>, I`
```

which requires you to do something you're not allowed to do :

```
class Unit<I> : Object<Unit<I>, I>, I
```

Comment: Honestly, i can't grasp the second part of your post. And i don't see how replacing of actual classes with interfaces can help me here, btw.

Comment: Guys, you are trying to show me how to simplify the model. But sadly, it's not the question i've asked in first place.

Comment: Its a simplification resulting in the same error (I'm on visual studio 2015 and wording seems different). Basically I believe your problem is the compiler isn't able to convert `Unit<D, I>  to I` because the conditions require that `Unit<D, I>` *is* `I` and the above shows that in simpler terms.

Comment: But why? Unit<D, I> is implementing IUnit, and "I" (following the mentioned constraint) is something which is IUnit or derived from IUnit. Isn't it?

Comment: I'd guess its because it can't do covarience. If you fix I to IUnit it becomes happy. `class Unit<D, I> : Object<D, Unit<D, I>, IUnit>, IUnit`

Comment: Well... It is hard to follow your reasoning when you continually updating your post, but I can agree with the conclusion in your last edit. Still your variant of simplification doesn't look to me logically equal to the initial code. If we replace definition of Unit to the one which is closer to my model:
`class Unit<I> : Object<Unit<I>, I>, IUnit where I : IUnit { }`, then I still don't see why compiler can't convert `Unit<I>` to `I` (where `I` is `IObject`, and as we know `Unit<I>` is also derived from `IObject`).

Comment: Because the condition: `where O : Object<O, I>, I` requires `Unit<I>` implement `I`...and it never will, because `I` can be something *more* derived than `IUnit`.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have commented, your generics are too complex.
At least, it seems to me, that there's no need for `I` type parameter, because your `Object`s will implement corresponding interface.

So, the code could be simplified like this:

```
abstract class Object<D, O> : IObject
    where D : ObjectData
    where O : Object<D, O>
{
}

class Unit<D> : Object<D, Unit<D>>, IUnit
    where D : UnitData
{
}
```

Without full understanding, how `O` will be used inside of `Object`s hierarchy, it is hard to say, is it possible to throw away `O` type parameter.

You've mentioned a static factory method - this is definitely not a reason to bring such complexity. But, of course, you know more about use cases.

Comment: "I" is defined to implement IEquatable<I> and IComparable<I> on Object. Also there is an Collection class nested within the Object which is implementing IEnumerable<I>. Yes, i know this hierarchy turned out to be too complex. And i've specified this in the caption. What i want to understand is the reason of an error - it doesn't look rational to me. But thanks for your answer anyway. Maybe I really need to simplify all of this.